# Matlab : save a spectrogram in a variable and display it

Tags: matlab, spectrogram

What I want is quite simple, or so I thought. I have many spectograms to compute and display which is time consuming to compute, so I want to save them in variables to display them without redoing the computation. The problem is that I can't find a way to plot them like they appear if I directly use the function spectogram().

Example :

```
sampling_rate = 100;
spectrogram(data,100,20,[],sampling_rate,'yaxis');
caxis([-20 60])
```

This displays a spectogram exactly as I want it :

[image: Spectrogram]

I read the doc and I understand that I can save the results by doing something like this :

`[S,F,T] = spectrogram(data,100,20,[],sampling_rate);`

Also, I know that the function spectogram internally calls surf().

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15918646/9149213) that seems to give a solution to my problem by doing this :

```
[S,F,T] = spectrogram(data,100,20,[],sampling_rate);
surf(T,F,abs(S),'EdgeColor','none');
axis tight; view(0,90);
```

But I get this plot, which is far from what I expected:

[image: Empty spectrogram]

The axis labels and colorbar are gone, and the colors are completely not scaled. If I do this manually by adding `colorbar; caxis([-20 60]);` as previously, I get this thing:

[image: Bad spectrogram]

Isn't there a simple solution to save a spectogram and display it on command ?

Like `S = spectogram(...)` then `plot(S)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987569/7328782) works more or less as expected, then the following shorter code should do the same:

```
[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(data(1:3000),100,20,[],sampling_rate);
h = imagesc(T,F,10*log10(P),[-20,60]);
xlabel('Time (secs)')
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
colorbar;
```

(I don't have the data to test it with.) Note that here the x and y ticks are set automatically. If you want to select seconds, minutes, hours depending on the scale of T, you could do:

```
lab = 'Time (secs)';
if T(end) > 60*60*3
   T = T/(60*60);
   lab = 'Time (hours)';
elseif T(end) > 60*3
   T = T/60;
   lab = 'Time (mins)'
end
h = imagesc(T,F,10*log10(P),[-20,60]);
xlabel(lab)
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
colorbar;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted !! Thank you so much, this works perfectly I love it !

Answer (score 3):

I found a beginning of solution.

If I write :

`[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(data(1:3000),100,20,[],sampling_rate);`

P saves the spectral power density in a matrix, which is quite convenient to plot **without forgetting to add 10*log10(P)**:

```
h = pcolor(10*log10(P));
colorbar;
caxis([-20 60]);
set(h,'EdgeColor','none')
```

And I get this which is much better:

[image]

But I'm still missing the time and frequency axis, because it currently displays the dimension of the matrix P.

**Edit**:

I finally found some sort of solution which would be dealing with the axis manually. The display of the time is still terrible and I'm certain there is a better way but here we go:

```
[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(data(1001:3000),100,50,[],sampling_rate);
h = pcolor(10*log10(P));
cb = colorbar;
caxis([-20 60]);
ylabel(cb, 'Power/frequency (dB/Hz')
set(h,'EdgeColor','none')

xticks(0:round(size(P,2)/6):size(P,2)) 
xt = xticks;
xticklabels([T(xt(2)) T(xt(2:end))]);
xlabel('Time (secs)');

yticks([0:13:size(P,1) size(P,1)])
yt = yticks;
yticklabels(0:5:50);
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
```

[image]

The time is saved in the vector T which is decently convenient in order to apply it on the x label. The frequency is stored F but in my case it'll always be between 0-50Hz so I wrote it manually.

I hope it'll help some people, and **if you know how to properly set the time axis** with automatic labelisation (sec, min, hours set automatically depending on the duration), by all means I would love to know.